# Trying to creat an IronRuby project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, ironruby

I have some code that I've cloned from GitHub. I am trying to create an IronRuby project in Visual studio 2013, and then import this code into Visual Studio. Once configuration is complete I should be able to modify using markdown.

I downloaded IronRuby, but it seems a bug in the installer puts the binaries in the wrong spot.

I found the binaries here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

And moved them here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\IronRuby (as well as attempting several other locations).

However, Visual Studio is not recognizing and not allowing me to open an Iron Ruby project. (As far as I am aware, once the binaries are saved, Visual Studio should recognize them and offer this as a project type.)

1. Where exactly do I need to save the files to be able to open an IronRuby project? (I have a 64 bit OS.)
2. Are there other configurations I need to consider for IronRuby in Visual Studio?
3. Alternative to Visual Studio, what is the best IDE to import a cloned Ruby project into?

I don't have much experience with open source so I apologize for the noobness and appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Visual Studio integration only works with/up to VS2010.

I had the same problem with my own IronRuby projects after migrating to VS2013. Searching for solutions, I only found that the IDE integration was discontinued.